# How to unit test class that performs get request

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, web-scraping

Say I want to scrape "long" posts from a particular website. In order to do this, I've created the following class:

```
import requests

class PostScraper:

    THRESHOLD = 100

    def __init__(self, thread_id):
        self.url = 'foo.bar/thread-%s?pg=last' % thread_id

    def get_long_posts(self):
        page = requests.get(self.url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
        posts = soup.find_all('div', 'post-text')
        return [post if len(post.text) > THRESHOLD for post in posts]
```

I'd like to write a unit test for this, but I'm not sure how to properly go about it... I'm imagining something like this pseudo-Python:

```
def test_getting_long_posts():
    scraper = PostScraper(None) # <- Not sure what to pass in. Advice?
    stub = {'text': '<html></html>', 'status': '200'}
    bind(url=scraper.url, response=stub)
    posts = scraper.get_long_posts()
    assert.equals(len(posts), 0)
```

I'm somewhat new to unit testing, particularly in Python. Does this approach even make sense? How *should* I go about this?

Comment: You probably don't want your method to do too much; it now gets the page, parses it, extracts all the posts, and filters them... It will become easier to test if you refactor into single purpose methods.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably best to write the class in such a way that the process of getting the text content of a url is separate from the process of scanning the text for suitable posts.

That way you can create your own hand-crafted html text with a known number of suitable posts, and test that your function finds exactly that number.

This would be one way to achieve the separation:

```
class PostScraper(object):

    THRESHOLD = 100

    def __init__(self, thread_id):
        self.url = 'foo.bar/thread-%s?pg=last' % thread_id
        self.content = None

    def fetch_page(self):
        self.content = requests.get(self.url).content

    def get_long_posts(self):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(self.content, 'html.parser')
        posts = soup.find_all('div', 'post-text')
        return [post if len(post.text) > THRESHOLD for post in posts]
```

When testing the code, you wouldn't call `fetch_page()` at all, but instead you could just directly assign `self.content` to be whatever fake page content you've created.